# I need help simplifying code that compares various properties of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a strong suspicion my code is way too clunky and can be written in a more concise and efficient manner. The intent is to compare an array of objects (representing players) to find the player with the highest majorityScore property. If there are more than one player sharing the same high score, then compare the co-winners' factions with a map (priorityMap) to determine who wins.

```
players = [
  {
    majorityScore: 4,
    faction: 'AR'
  },
  {
    majorityScore: 8,
    faction: 'MOU'
  },
  {
    majorityScore: 2,
    faction: 'MOB'
  },
  {
    majorityScore: 8,
    faction: 'I'
  }
];

const priorityMap = {
  'MOB': 1,
  'I': 2,
  'MOU': 3,
  'AR': 4,
  'S' : 0
}

let winner;
let highScore = -1;
let duplicates = [];
for(let i = 0; i < players.length; i++){
  if(players[i].majorityScore > highScore){
    highScore = players[i].majorityScore;
    winner = players[i]
    duplicates = [winner];
  } else if (players[i].majorityScore === highScore){
    duplicates.push(players[i]);
  };
}
if(duplicates.length > 1){
  let highFactionScore = duplicates.reduce((a,v) => {
    if(priorityMap[v.faction] > a){
      a = priorityMap[v.faction];
    }
    return a;
  }, 0);
  let winningFaction = Object.keys(priorityMap).find((k) => {
    return priorityMap[k] === highFactionScore;
  });
  winner = duplicates.filter((v) => {
    return v.faction === winningFaction
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are reducing an array of objects into one object, the reduce function can be used here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Instead of checking the factions after getting the players with the highest majority score, you can check the factions whenever you end up comparing players with the same majority score.

```
let winner = players.reduce((accum, currVal) => {
    if (accum.majorityScore < currVal.majorityScore) {
        return currVal;
    } else if (accum.majorityScore > currVal.majorityScore) {
        return accum;
    } else {
        return priorityMap[accum.faction] > priorityMap[currVal.faction] ? accum : currVal
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly shorter method. It uses a temp object to maintain a dictionary where the scores are the keys. As we iterate we add the value of `priorityMap[faction]` to the score property, and change it only if the value is greater than the one stored.

```js
const players=[{majorityScore:4,faction:"AR"},{majorityScore:8,faction:"MOU"},{majorityScore:8,faction:"MOU12"},{majorityScore:8,faction:"MOU20"},{majorityScore:2,faction:"MOB"},{majorityScore:2,faction:"MOB2"},{majorityScore:8,faction:"I"}],priorityMap={MOB:1,I:2,MOU:3,MOB2:4,AR:4,S:0,MOU12:21,MOU20:22};

function getGroups(arr) {

  // Create the temp object
  // We'll be using the scores as keys, and using
  // the value in priorityMap as the value
  // As we iterate we check the new priorityMap value
  // against the old one
  const temp = {};

  // Iterate over the players array
  return arr.reduce((acc, c) => {
    const { majorityScore: score, faction } = c;

    // If the accumulator object doesn't have a key that
    // matches the score, add a new object
    acc[score] = (acc[score] || { majorityScore: score, faction });

    // If the new value of priorityMap[faction] is
    // greater than the one stored in temp
    // update the faction in the accumulator for that score
    if (priorityMap[faction] > temp[score]) {
      acc[score].faction = faction;
    }

    // Update the temp object with the
    // priorityMap[faction] value
    temp[score] = priorityMap[faction];

    // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(getGroups(players));
```